# How to install dependencies using pip install in VS Code on macOS Catalina

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-3.6, macos-catalina

I created a new virtual environment on VS Code in python 3.6.2 using `python3 venv venv` and activated it using `venv/bin/activate`. Then I tried to install speech recognition using `pip install speechrecognition` but, it give me an error saying:

```
bash: /Users/naman/Documents/Ai Assistant/assistant/bin/pip: "/Users/naman/Documents/Ai: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I cannot install anything using pip install in the new virtual environment. Please Help!
Im using VS Code on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Python and `pip` in `/Users/naman/Documents/Ai Assistant/assistant/bin/`. Unfortunately that path contains a space and Unix (MacOS X in your case) doesn't like spaces in paths to executable files.

The problem is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Your `pip` has this as the first line:

```
#!/Users/naman/Documents/Ai Assistant/assistant/bin/python
```

When you execute `pip` the OS' kernel sees `#!` and understands it's a script that has to be run with an interpreter. The OS takes the first line and split it by spaces. Here is the problem: the OS tries to run `/Users/naman/Documents/Ai` as the interpreter and failed.

My advice is to re-install Python and `pip` into a directory without spaces in its full path.

A workaround for your current situation is to run `python` manually. Either

```
python -m pip install speechrecognition
```

or

```
"/Users/naman/Documents/Ai Assistant/assistant/bin/python" -m pip install speechrecognition
```

Please note quotes — they prevent the command interpreter to split by spaces so that the entire `/Users/naman/Documents/Ai Assistant/assistant/bin/python` becomes one path to the interpreter. There is no way to use quotes and avoid splitting in the shebang line.