# /Mobile Documents/ stops 'python3 setup.py install' working properly

Tags: python-3.x, macos, setuptools

I have a python script located here on my Mac:

```
/Users/mark/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development/Python New/Tkinter_template_cx_freeze/Python
```

The setup.py file references some code and I am expecting to be able to use a command line function abc:

```
from setuptools import setup

with open('README.rst', 'r') as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup (
    name='TKINTER_TEMPLATE_CX_FREEZE',
    version='1.0',
    author='Mark ',
    author_email='....',
    description='blah de blah',
    url="...",
    license='PICK A LICENSE PLEASE',
    long_description=long_description,
    packages=['main_app'],
    install_requires=[''],
    python_requires='==3.6',
    package_data={},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'abc = main_app:main_tkinter_app'
        ]
    }

)
```

I attempt to build a distribution file using the following:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

I then create a virtual environment and install the application as follows:

```
python3 -m venv venv_test_dist; source venv_test_dist/bin/activate; python3 setup.py install
```

I then attempt to run abc and this generally fails with the following error message:

```
bash: /Users/mark/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Development/Python New/Tkinter_template_cx_freeze/Python/venv_test_dist/bin/abc: "/Users/mark/Library/Mobile: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It is weird that the 'Mobile' part of the path stops this from working, so I tried moving it to a different directory with no spaces present and everything works fine.   It is as if the space in the path is stopping 'setup.py install' from working.

Is there a way to fix this ?   I would like to keep all of my python files where they are because they are on my 'iCloud Drive', which seems to reference

```
'/Users/mark/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install dependencies using pip install in VS Code on macOS Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173477/how-to-install-dependencies-using-pip-install-in-vs-code-on-macos-catalina)

Comment: In short: no way. Unix shebang doesn't allow spaces.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer